# Passing API POST to stripe with business type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Stripe news API update for Connect accounts doesn't allow the "legal_entity" param for new stripe accounts.  The new updated way is for "business_type".. But the issue i have is that I need to pass data from either of the 2 choices for business_type of "individual" or "company.

**This is the old way that worked:**

```
      acct = Stripe::Account.create({
      :country => stripe_account_params[:country],
      :type => "custom",
        legal_entity: {
          first_name: stripe_account_params[:first_name].capitalize,
          last_name: stripe_account_params[:last_name].capitalize,
          type: stripe_account_params[:account_type],
          dob: {
            day: stripe_account_params[:dob_day],
            month: stripe_account_params[:dob_month],
            year: stripe_account_params[:dob_year]
          },
          address: {
            line1: stripe_account_params[:address_line1],
            city: stripe_account_params[:address_city],
            state: stripe_account_params[:address_state],
            postal_code: stripe_account_params[:address_postal]
          },
          ssn_last_4: stripe_account_params[:ssn_last_4]
        },
        tos_acceptance: {
          date: Time.now.to_i,
          ip: request.remote_ip
        }

})
```

**The new way (my attempt):**

```
acct = Stripe::Account.create({
  :country => stripe_account_params[:country],
  :type => "custom",
  :business_type => stripe_account_params[:account_type],
  requested_capabilities: ['card_payments'],
    # company: {
    #   name: stripe_account_params[:business_name],
    #   phone: stripe_account_params[:business_phone],
    #   phone: stripe_account_params[:business_tax_id],
    #     address: {
    #       line1: stripe_account_params[:business_address_line1],
    #       city: stripe_account_params[:business_address_city],
    #       state: stripe_account_params[:business_address_state],
    #       postal_code: stripe_account_params[:business_address_postal]
    #     },
    #   },
    individual: {
      address: stripe_account_params[:address_line1],
      first_name: stripe_account_params[:first_name],
      last_name: stripe_account_params[:last_name],
      ssn_last_4: stripe_account_params[:ssn_last_4],
      # phone: stripe_account_params[:business_tax_id],
        dob: {
          day: stripe_account_params[:dob_day],
          month: stripe_account_params[:dob_month],
          year: stripe_account_params[:dob_year]
        },
        address: {
          line1: stripe_account_params[:address_line1],
          city: stripe_account_params[:address_city],
          state: stripe_account_params[:address_state],
          postal_code: stripe_account_params[:address_postal]
        },
      },
    tos_acceptance: {
      date: Time.now.to_i,
      ip: request.remote_ip
    }

})
```

With the section i have commented out, not commented out, I get this error:
(If i choose individual with the commented out area, it will work)

I tried simply not defining the address, etc. and loosely having the params and see if Stripe will decide where they go and that didn't work so it seems as if they need to be defined like above but i don't know how to distinguish them.

> You cannot provide both `company` and `individual` parameters. Only
>   provide them accordingly with the `business_type` on the account.

Now, the fields are named the same within stripe:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create

So i am unsure how i can pass this through.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Update: So it looks like simply doing in the controller `if @stripe_account.account_type == "company" (code here with company only acct) elsif @stripe_account.account_type =="individual" (individual code here)` may be working... still testing this out.

Comment: Hi! Did you solve this problem? How? I'm trying to create a connect account via API but it says "Received unknown parameter: business_type".